# Ordenação de String customizada

Tags: php, lógica

Olá, estou com um problema, preciso ordenar um conjunto de letras em ordem alfabética, porém a ordem das palavras é customizado a partir de uma ordem de letras especificas.

```
<?php
     // Pega o conteudo do arquivo texto.
    $arquivo = file_get_contents("texto.txt") or die("Falha ao pega o conteudo!");
    // Pega as palavras do arquivo e guarda cada palavra em uma posição da array.
    $resultado = explode(" ", $arquivo);

    $ordenado = array();

    //array de inicialização do alfabeto booglan
    function cmpA($a,$b){
        $alfabeto_boo = array('t','w','h','z','k','d','f','v','c','j','x','l','r','n','q','m','g','p','s','b');

        if(strcmp(substr($a, 0,1), substr($b, 0,1)) == 0){
            echo "$a:$b<br>";
            return 0;
        }
        return (array_search($a,$alfabeto_boo) < array_search($b,$alfabeto_boo)) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    usort($resultado, "cmpA");
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($resultado,true) . '</pre>';

?>
```

Mas com o usort, ele está me retornando ordenador, porém não na ordem determinada pelo alfabeto proposto.

Comment: Vc pode editar a pergunta que fez anteriormente, do que criar outra, se o propósito for o mesmo. Aí ela vai para reabertura

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não rolou. Não sei oque houve, eu também sou novo por aqui.

Comment: Sobre o proposito, não são iguais, mas tem a msm ideia, no outro tópico, eu já conseguir resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Criei um `script`, baseado no seu, que resolverá seu problema. O código está comentado.

```
<?php 

$resultado  = array("wtps", "tdtt", "tktf"); // aqui é o resultado do explode
$posicoes = array();

echo '<pre>' . print_r($resultado ,true) . '</pre>';

/*

A função abaixo identifica as posições de cada caracter de cada string analisada

*/

function identificaPosicoes(&$string){
    $quantidadeDeCarcteres = 16; // aqui você define o máximo de caracteres que cada string terá
    // coloquei 16 pois acho que é suficiente
    $alfabeto_boo = array('t','w','h','z','k','d','f','v','c','j','x','l','r','n','q','m','g','p','s','b');
    $stringPos = array();
    for($x = 0; $x < $quantidadeDeCarcteres; $x++){
        if(isset($string[$x])){
            for($y = 0; $y < count($alfabeto_boo); $y++){
                if($string[$x] == $alfabeto_boo[$y]){
                    $stringPos[] = $y;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $stringPos[] = 0;
        }
    }
    return $stringPos;
}

$posicoes = array_map("identificaPosicoes",$resultado); // aqui ele analisa as posições e retona tudo para um array
asort($posicoes); // aqui ele ordena o array sem alterar o valor das chaves

$ordenados = array();
foreach($posicoes as $chave => $valor){
    $ordenados[] = $resultado[$chave]; // aqui ele pega o valor das chaves na ordem para ordenar o resultado
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($ordenados,true) . '</pre>'; // aqui ele gera o resultado
```

usando o seu array:

```
array("nqkrm", "dbpvxzj", "bsthm", "cjwdc", "qflzwj", "mxnr", "xbzj", "pspb", "kcwr", "trf", "csw", "frqfs", "mmkrjpcz");
```

O resultado foi esse:

```
Array
(
    [0] => trf
    [1] => kcwr
    [2] => dbpvxzj
    [3] => frqfs
    [4] => cjwdc
    [5] => csw
    [6] => xbzj
    [7] => nqkrm
    [8] => qflzwj
    [9] => mxnr
    [10] => mmkrjpcz
    [11] => pspb
    [12] => bsthm
)
```

Comment: Opa, então, não existe as letras A, E, I, O, U. 
As letras são assim: nqkrm dbpvxzj bsthm cjwdc qflzwj mxnr xbzj pspb kcwr trf csw frqfs mmkrjpcz rvtfn ztcbglxj bnpbjz spmcmpls bdlr fwscncn wksx tnxn hpmwbs ftcxbv whqn.
Engraçado, que com o jeito que voocê fez, realmente funcionou.

Comment: @LuizMiguel tem uma outra solução... vou editar.. Espera ai.

Comment: @LuizMiguel colocando aquele if antes do ULTIMO return, qualquer caractere ou letra que não existe no seu array retornará -1. Então irá para o final e não para o começo.

Comment: @LuizMiguel não existe vogal no texto?

Comment: Então, problema que ele não está ordenando certo. Acho que é algum problema de lógico, q eu não percebi. 
Como está vindo o resultado:
Array
(
    [0] => hnh
    [1] => xdrbsmwn
    [2] => kxp
    [3] => dmddhsk
    [4] => hzlvdfhw
  ....
}

Comment: Não existe nenhuma vogal no texto

Comment: @LuizMiguel O problema está no seu array. Vou editar a resposta e veja se funciona.

Comment: @LuizMiguel tente usar o trim para apagar espaçamentos igual eu fiz.

Comment: @LuizMiguel fiz outros testes e está vindo errado mesmo. Vou pesquisar e se eu puder ajudar eu posto uma nova resposta.

Comment: @LuizMiguel creio que consegui oque você quer.

Comment: @LuizMiguel deu certo?

Comment: Andrei, muito obrigado de verdade, eu conseguir usando com o que você compartilhou comigo!

Comment: @LuizMiguel se você achar que a resposta foi útil, por favor avalie

Comment: Eu avaliei, mas apareceu que com usuário com menos que 15 de reputação, não mostra a pontuação. Mas eu avaliei sim. PS sou novato aqui no stackoverflow! 
Muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: @LuizMiguel tranquilo. =) Abraço!